# Normalisation of practise database

Tags: normalization

I am a newbie to database design, and I'm a bit confused about how to create a database with minimum redundancy. Suppose I have a table `abc` with repetition of data in it and no two rows are same. Now to reduce repetition? I follow normalisation rules and break the table `abc` into other tables with relations to table `abc`. Now is it a fair practise to add a primary key in table `abc` explictly which will identify each row uniquely, or we can ignore adding primary key?

If primary key is added in table `abc` and table `abc` contain a column `authid (int)`. then it collides with the primary key value in it.

**Update**

To elaborate a flat db `abc` suppose i have a `library table` with columns

```
ISBN   Title   Auid   Auname   Auphone   Pubid  Pubname   pubphone   price
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
11111  C++      4     Roman    2147483647  1   Big House    1234567890  20
9999   Emma     1     Austen   1111111111  1   Big House    1234567890  20
9133   Faeri    7     Spenser  2147483647  1   Big House    1234567890  15
9104   Hamlet   5  Shakespeare 2147483647  2   Alpha Press  2147483647  20
1034   Iliad    3    Homer     2147483647  1   Big House    1234567890  25
1234   Jane     1    Austen    1111111111  3   Small House  2147483647  49
9977   King     5  Shakespeare 2147483647  2   Alpha press  2147483647  49
5555   Macbeth  5  Shakespeare 2147483647  2   Alpha press  2147483647  12
```

here in this `lib table` we may have same `ISBN`in two rows but any two rows are unique.the repeatations of data is obvious as shown and to reduce that we can break the table and follow normaliation

**Books**

```
Title
ISBN
Price
ISBN primary key
```

**Authors**

```
AuName
AuPhone
AuID
Auid primary key
```

**Publishers**

```
PubName
PubPhone
PubID
Pubid primary
```

and:

**book/author**

```
ISBN
Auid
```

to maintain book/author relation

So can I add primary key explicitly in flat `library table` or how to acheive normalisation? I think I should add primary key else no relation. Is this breaking enough to achieve normalisation or any other concept or review is always welcome?
Following example from *Access Database Design & Programming, 3rd Edition by Steven Roman*

Comment: It is not at all clear what you are asking. Please try to clarify, add examples of tables (with columns and data), before and after the normalization step.

Comment: But in general, if a table has no two rows identical, then you can simply use the combination of all columns `(a, b, c, ..., z)` as the primary key. There is no need to add another (surrogate) column. (it's common in many DBMS, for various reasons, but it is not needed.) But as @marc_s says, you do need at least one unique constraint or a primary key defined.

Comment: By default, **every** table **ought to have** a primary key! It's what reliably, uniquely identifies each row of the table - so **NO**, by no means just *ignore adding primary key* to your tables! That's a horrible design ....

Comment: yes . sorry for not posting the db schemas and table structure.i will be posting it.thnx

Comment: i have given a new problem elaborating the tables and issues. kindly have a look [here](http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/59225/acheiving-normalisation-with-practise-databse) thnkx for your concern

Comment: thnx for the edit :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your breakup of the table is largely correct.  There is three tangible objects, a book, the author, and the publisher.  Each of these needs a table, we also need a table to store the relationship between Authors and Books and Publishers and Books as these relationships are many to many.

**Books**

```
ISBN (primary key)
Title
Price
```

**Authors**

```
AuId (primary key)
AuName 
AuPhone
```

**Publishers**

```
PubId (primary key)
PubName
PubPhone
```

**Authors to Books**

```
AuBId (primary key)
AuId (composite key)
ISBN (composite key)
```

**Publishers to Books**

```
PubBId (primary key)
PubId (composite key)
ISBN (composite key)
```

You could just use the composite keys instead of having an explicit primary key on the last two tables that define the many-to-many relationships.

**Edit:**

When I say composite key I mean if a primary key exists that it is an alternate unique key made of multiple columns.  If there is no other primary key defined then the primary key would be defined as both columns, i.e. `PubId` and `ISBN`.  There are both pros and cons for doing using a composite key as the primary key, people have different takes on the best option.

There is no reason to explicitly store the libary table with the table structure above, all the information is already stored.  If absolutely necessary I would think that the ISBN is unique, if not you could as mentioned add a primary key column like serialno which maintain integrity.

Comment: ok so this mean that if i use the composite key as you have mentioned then no need of `AuBid` and `PubBid` as primary key explictly? and what about flat `library table` there should be an added primary key column like `serialno` which maintain integrity.and can you please explain why composite key not primary key in `Author/books` table and `publisher/books` and how to declare a composite key if possible the table structure for any of the two. thank you so much.

Comment: There are 2 schools of thought when it comes to many to many relation tables, A single column primary key for the table or a composite key based on the 2 foreign keys to the other tables.  I prefer the composite key since it is cleaner but that could start a star trek vs star wars style debate.  Either way as long as the keys are foreign keyed to the original table you may get a funny look or 2 but that is all.  For the flat library table once you have broken it apart you don't really need it around any more.

Comment: i dont understand why its off-topic.when you got a tag `normalisation` and its fully releated to that then why its put on-hold.